# Running APK on Emulator: "Unfortunately, YourAPP has stopped."

Tags: android, android-emulator, coronasdk

My APK runs fine on my friends' devices but throws an "Unfortunately, YourAPP has stopped." error. How do I fix that in the emulator? I don't have an android device so I need to get it to work. I can't always borrow other people's devices.

The app is already in Google Play as a draft with the in-app purchases ready. I just want to test some things out more (my integration with Corona Cloud/Game Minion)

The app was made with Corona SDK, and I downloaded the Android SDK to run the emulator. The emulator shows up, the APK installs successfully, just that it won't run.

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Answer (score 3):

FOUND WHAT WAS WRONG!

I turned on DDMS and saw these lines:

> 12-19 13:44:52.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2445): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 144
>   12-19 13:44:52.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2445): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec

A quick Google search revealed that I just had to turn GPU emulation on. GAWDDANGIT!

Comment: Could you accept this answer and remove the question from the unanswered tab?

Answer (score 0):

If your application uses bluetooth it won't function properly on the Emulator as they do not support Bluetooth.